# Breakpoint does not hit at controller action when called through Ajax call

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, actionmethod

I am making following AJAX call to a method in controller

```
var jsonParams = { name: $('#txt_name').val(), address: $('#txt_addr').val() };
var json = JSON.stringify(jsonParams);
var actionUrl = "/AddressController/SaveAddress"; 

alert('all ok');  //alert arrives
$.ajax({      
        url: actionUrl,
        data: json,
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',   
        success: function (response) {
            // success message
        }
});
```

And here is my controller action method

```
public JsonResult SaveAddress(string name, string address)
{
      //code
}
```

Here I have put the breakpoint at SaveAddress method however when I tried to debug the code using firebug, the Ajax is called but the breakpoint does not arrive at method. Also it does nothing,.. no response, no success message, as if it is not hitting the action method at all.

What I am doing wrong here. I tried all the suggested answers posted for the similar type of questions but none of them worked.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The request has to be doing *something*. Check it in the network tab of the console to see the response code and text.

Comment: I believe the url is wrong, it should not have Controller part, just `/Address/SaveAddress`

Comment: What @Andrei said is true, but also you could have to add the [AllowPost] attribute on your method depending on the settings of your application

Comment: @Andrei I tried removing 'Controller' but still its not working

Answer (score 0):

You can create a viewModel Like that your JsonParams Property,and getting your JSON.stringify from your controller by ViewModel.

```
Public class TestViewModel
{
  public string name {get;set;}
  public string address{get;set;}
}

public JsonResult SaveAddress(TestViewModel json)
{
  //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below url, as your controller method is accepting two parameters not the json string.

```
var actionUrl = "/Address/SaveAddress?name=" + $('#txt_name').val() +"&address=" + $('#txt_addr').val();
```